# MPMoviePlayerController can not play ts

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

there is one ts file in my localhost , I can play it by VLC, but can not play by MPMoviePlayerController in simulator

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/test.ts"]];
```

The information of ts file is :

[image]

Comment: It is merely a different codec that is unsupported by the MediaPlayer Framework, at a guess. VLC would have written or obtained one to playback the file in their app.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [iOS Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html):

> The video technologies in iOS support the playback of movie files with the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename extensions and using the following compression standards: ...

So, your file cannot be player not because of codec, but because of video container format. iOS doesn't understand MPEG TS.